# can't change value by key

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. I have a tree structure and I want to change "tags" property value from an array of strings to a string when the array length is bigger than 5.

```
ChangeTags(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      (key === 'tags' && obj[key].length > 5) && obj["tags"] = "some value" ||
      (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') && this.removeEmptyNodes(obj[key]);
    });
    return obj;
  };
```

The interpreter does not allow me to do the assignment in the 4th line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do in your code based on your description... you show length > 1 for example. Why do you set (=) "some value" to tags? if you wanted to compare it (with ===), why do you need to compare it to "some value"?

Comment: I've edited my question. My bad, > 1 was for testing purposes. I want to set tags field to "some value", when the array length is bigger then 5

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is brackets. try this:

```
ChangeTags(obj) {
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  ((key === 'tags' && obj[key].length > 5) && obj["tags"] = "some value") ||
  ((obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') && this.removeEmptyNodes(obj[key]));
});
return obj;
};
```

Comment: That's still invalid JavaScript. The stuff on the left side of the "=" is not an lvalue: `((key === 'tags' && obj[key].length > 5) && obj["tags"] = "some value")`

Comment: yes it is not proper way i am agree with with you , i just showed his logic mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet your needs?

```js
//  I have a tree structure and I want to change "tags" field value from array of strings to string when the array length is bigger than 5

const objs = [
  { id: 1, tags: ['first', 'second'] },
  { id: 2, tags: ['first'] },
  { id: 3, tags: ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth'] }
];

function changeTags(arr) {
  for (let obj of arr) {
    obj.tags.length > 5 && (obj.tags = "some value");
  }
}

changeTags(objs);
console.log(objs);
```

Or for each case as you do in your example (you were missing parenthesis in the assignment):

```js
const obj = { tags: [1,2,3,4,5,6] };
const obj2 = { tags: ["a", "b"] };

function ChangeTags(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      (key === 'tags' && obj[key].length > 5) && (obj["tags"] = "some value") ||
      (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object')  // && this.removeEmptyNodes(obj[key]); commented this out for the test
    });
    return obj;
};

console.log(ChangeTags(obj));
console.log(ChangeTags(obj2));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid JavaScript:

```
(key === 'tags' && obj[key].length > 5) && obj["tags"] = "some value"
```

The left-side of an assignment must be a variable or an object property.

It seems you are attempting to set `obj.tags` to "some value" when its array length is greater than 5. Here is a valid way to accomplish that:

```
(key === 'tags' && obj[key].length > 5) && (obj["tags"] = "some value")
```

By surrounding `obj["tags"] = "some value"` with parentheses, the left-side of the assignment becomes simply `obj["tags"]`, which is an object property.